# How can I split a DataFrame column with datetimes into two columns: one with dates and one with times of the day?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, series

I have a data frame called `data`, which has a column `Dates` like this,

```
                 Dates
0  2015-05-13 23:53:00
1  2015-05-13 23:53:00
2  2015-05-13 23:33:00
3  2015-05-13 23:30:00
4  2015-05-13 23:30:00
```

I know how to add a column to data frame, but how to divide `Dates` to

```
          Day         Time
0  2015-05-13     23:53:00
1  2015-05-13     23:53:00
2  2015-05-13     23:33:00
3  2015-05-13     23:30:00
4  2015-05-13     23:30:00
```

Comment: What type of data is 'Dates'? What is the output of df.Dates.iat[0]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your series is `s`, then this will create such a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(s).dt.date,
    'time': pd.to_datetime(s).dt.time})
```

as once you convert the series using [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then the `dt` member can be used to extract the parts.

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['2015-05-13 23:53:00', '2015-05-13 23:53:00'])
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.to_datetime(s).dt.date,
    'time': pd.to_datetime(s).dt.time})
    date    time
0   2015-05-13  23:53:00
1   2015-05-13  23:53:00
```

Comment: Can you save the time column values in 12 hours format instead of a 24 hour format???

Comment: @sanster9292 See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Comment: Ami, I am not great with this. I have data in a pandas columns that looks like this. 

1999-01-01T00:00:29.75

I want to split and save it and Eastern Daylight Time. How would I handle the T in there?

This is what I am doing so far,

Comment: df3['Day']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',errors='coerce').dt.tz_localize('UTC')

Comment: @sanster9292 Could you please ask this as a question? Comments are not meant for this stuff. Plenty of people will help you out.

Comment: Thanks Ami. Let me post this as a question

Comment: @sanster9292 If you'd like, place here a link to your question, and I'll be glad to have a look.

Comment: Ami, here is the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030619/how-to-get-hours-minute-seconds-from-iso-8601-date-time-format

Answer (score 1):

If your `Dates` column is a string:

```
data['Day'], data['Time'] = zip(*data.Dates.str.split())

>>> data
                 Dates         Day      Time
0  2015-05-13 23:53:00  2015-05-13  23:53:00
1  2015-05-13 23:53:00  2015-05-13  23:53:00
2  2015-05-13 23:33:00  2015-05-13  23:33:00
3  2015-05-13 23:33:00  2015-05-13  23:33:00
4  2015-05-13 23:33:00  2015-05-13  23:33:00
```

If it is a timestamp:

```
data['Day'], data['Time'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in data.Dates])
```

Answer (score 1):

If type of column `Dates` is string, convert it by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you can use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) original column `Dates`:

```
print df['Dates'].dtypes
object
print type(df.at[0, 'Dates'])
<type 'str'>

df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

print df['Dates'].dtypes
datetime64[ns]

print df
                Dates
0 2015-05-13 23:53:00
1 2015-05-13 23:53:00
2 2015-05-13 23:33:00
3 2015-05-13 23:30:00
4 2015-05-13 23:30:00

df['Date'] = df['Dates'].dt.date
df['Time'] = df['Dates'].dt.time

df = df.drop('Dates', axis=1)
print df
         Date      Time
0  2015-05-13  23:53:00
1  2015-05-13  23:53:00
2  2015-05-13  23:33:00
3  2015-05-13  23:30:00
4  2015-05-13  23:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

#### [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) + [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

You can use `operator.attrgetter` with `pd.concat` to add an arbitrary number of `datetime` attributes to your dataframe as separate series:

```
from operator import attrgetter

fields = ['date', 'time']
df = df.join(pd.concat(attrgetter(*fields)(df['Date'].dt), axis=1, keys=fields))

print(df)

                 Date        date      time
0 2015-05-13 23:53:00  2015-05-13  23:53:00
1 2015-01-13 15:23:00  2015-01-13  15:23:00
2 2016-01-13 03:33:00  2016-01-13  03:33:00
3 2018-02-13 20:13:25  2018-02-13  20:13:25
4 2017-05-12 06:52:00  2017-05-12  06:52:00
```